# Escaping args[0] in Powershell

Tags: powershell, parameters, process, terminate

I'm writing a script to terminate a process identified by it's Commandline call. It works fine if i hardcode it like:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "CommandLine LIKE '%worker04%'" | Invoke-WmiMethod -Name Terminate
```

Now I want to work with a parameter like this:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "CommandLine LIKE '%$args[0]%'" | Invoke-WmiMethod -Name Terminate
```

so I can call my script like this:

```
.\killprocess worker04
```

So far it does nothing. How do I correctly put the `$args[0]` in the `-Filter` block?

Comment: Don't use `$args` in the first place. Use named parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will do it:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "CommandLine LIKE '%$($args[0])%'" | Invoke-WmiMethod -Name Terminate
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem in the for loop and `%$($args[0])%` does not work for me. I made it with something like that:

```
for($i; $i -lt $args.length ;$i++)
{
$arg=$args[$i]
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "CommandLine LIKE '$arg'...... 
}
```

It works fine here.